# IOS: store a json with array and object nested

Tags: ios, database, core-data, nsarray, nsdictionary

I have a question about creating a database with core data.
In my app at first start I should parse some json to obtain some data to insert in core data db.
my json files are structured in this way: (I show only an element of my json)

```
[{"id":"s1",
"n":"Name hotel",
"id_loc":["l1","l2","l3","l4"],
"val":3,
"tel1":"12345678",
"tel2":"12345678",
"obj":
{"id":"o1",
"n":"Name",
"des":"description",
"flag":"red"}
}]
```

I understand that I can consider this as an entity in coredata and consider all element as attribute, it's clear.
Now you can see that inside my json there is an array "id_loc" and an object (or dictionary) "obj".
In core data what's the way to manage these two elements?
I suppose that "obj" can be managed as a new entity, and "id_loc", what's the way to set it in my core data DB?
Can you help me?
Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For `obj`, it's as you suggest: create a new entity, and set up a relationship between the two entities.

For `id_loc` it depends on how you need to use the data.

- If you just want to have that data available when you look up an instance (that is, you maybe display this data but don't ned to search for it), you can store the strings in an `NSArray`. Make the attribute *transformable* in the Core Data model editor, and Core Data will read/write the complete array.
- If you need to look up data based on `id_loc` values (for example: Find every object where `id_loc` contains `l3`), the best approach is to create another entity to hold values of `id_loc`, and set up a to-many relationship to that new entity.

Comment: Yes, you're right, id_loc is important because I use it as your second example... then I should create a new entity for id_loc but how? id_loc can contain a variable number of elements, and how can I set this new entity? how many attributes?

Comment: You'd create an `id_loc` that has a **single** attribute, which is a string. Then your main entity would have a to-many relationship, so it could relate to as many of those single-attribute objects as it needs. You end up with an `NSSet` of objects, and each object corresponds to a single `id_loc` string.

Comment: I created a new entity called 'Id_loc' with single attribute, as a string; I created a to-many relationship for the main entity. Now I generated the classes for the main identity and for id_loc; now in main identity class I see two mthods: '- (void)addLocObject:(Id_loc *)value;
- (void)addLoc:(NSSet *)values;' Should I use only the second? So I take my id_loc array and insert inside it easy. Or should I use 'addLocObject'? But in this second case I should do a nasted loop and it's nnot directly...